# No entity framework provider found in unit test

Tags: c#, entity-framework, unit-testing

I'm new with Dependency Injection and Unit testing (in C#), but I want to learn that way to code and test.
Want I want to do is create a test that returns some search results from a function that I used in the ASP.NET program.

After a lot of searching on the internet I have created a test function. This is what I have so far, but it isn't working:

```
 [TestMethod]
    public void Search_for_a_movie()
    {
        //Arrange - create a mock repository
        Mock<IMovieRepository> mockMovieRepository = new Mock<IMovieRepository>();
        mockMovieRepository.Setup(m => m.SearchResults("Avatar")).Returns(new List<Movie>()
        {
            new Movie {MovieId = 1, MovieName = "Avatar"},
            new Movie {MovieId = 2, MovieName = "The Lion King"}
        });
        EFMovieRepository efMovieRepository = new EFMovieRepository();
        var result = efMovieRepository.SearchResults("Avatar");

        // Assert 
        Assert.IsNotNull(result, "It's not empty");
    }
```

On `var result = efMovieRepository.SearchResults("Avatar");` i'm getting a error:

```
No Entity Framework provider found for the ADO.NET provider with invariant name 'System.Data.SqlClient'. Make sure the provider is registered in the 'entityFramework' section of the application config file.
```

App.config:

```
 <entityFramework>
<defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
  <parameters>
    <parameter value="mssqllocaldb" />
  </parameters>
</defaultConnectionFactory>
<providers>
  <provider invariantName="System.Data.SqlClient" type="System.Data.Entity.SqlServer.SqlProviderServices, EntityFramework.SqlServer" />
</providers>
```

I have no idea what is wrong. Can you help me?

Comment: Is that the app.config of your _test project_? You also shouldn't mock the class you want to test, you're not doing anything with `mockMovieRepository`, you should inject a mock Entity Framework context into `new EFMovieRepository()`. That way your test won't need EF at all.

Comment: Ouch! That was the app.config from the domain project. Bad. Bad. Bad. I have pasted the <entityframework> section into that config file and now I'm getting a 'cannot initialize the configsystem'. But maybe it is the code now.

Comment: No, that means you're missing the relevant configsection (at least, that's the most common occurrence of that exception).

Comment: Since this is a Unit Test, it should not rely on a config entry. You need to find a way to not to use the config. But it is harder to say exactly as it is not clear what the code really does. Also the test does not look right as why would you ever want to Unit Test a repository (abstraction over data layer right)